# Proof using induction for Counting to 21 Game

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, induction

In a game with 2 players, who take turns saying up to 3 numbers, whoever says 21 is eliminated.

According to [this website](https://unstop.com/blog/game-21-challenge), I know that the second player can always win as long as they hit multiples of 4, and if they hit 16 they will inevitably win.

Is there a way to prove this strategy using induction? If so, please go through it step by step. Thanks.

Comment: You can prove it for 20 (first player must lose) and then 16 (second player can ensure first player will lose) and then 12 and so on down to 0.  You can call this induction

Comment: Whoever say the number $20$ wins, since the opponent is forced to say $21$ in the next turn. Now how to be the one who say $20$? What was the last number your opponent say before you say $20$?